# SQL запрос к БД с выводом нескольких столбцов

Tags: c#, sql

Добрый день. Есть таблица в БД, в таблице есть 4 столбца: Name, Date, Code, INN. Мне необходимо вывести с  помощью SQL запроса Name, Date, Code в консоль. Как вывести сразу три значения столбцов select Name, Date, Code from tRefuseTable where inn='{0}' ? Я пробовал вывести только Name

```
string ConString = "connstring;"; 

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = string.Format(@"select Name from tRefuseTable where inn='{0}'", item.INN_Legal);//текст запроса
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() ) ;//вывод результата на консоль
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ну так запрос поправьте - добавьте в него нужные столбцы, а потом уже берите `reader[0]`, `reader[1]`, `reader[2]` (а лучше `reader["Name"]` и т.д.)

Comment: Другой вариант - вместо индексатора воспользоваться подходящим методом `GetXXX(...)`, например `reader.GetString(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Для C# 6:

```
command.CommandText = string.Format(@"select Name, Date, Code from tRefuseTable where inn='{0}'", item.INN_Legal);//текст запроса
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name={reader[0]}, Date={reader[1]}, Code={reader[2]}");
}
```

Для предыдущих версий:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name={0}, Date={1}, Code={2}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]));
```

или ещё проще:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Date={1}, Code={2}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
```

Также, чтобы избежать потенциальный SQL-инъекций и дать возможность SQL-серверу кешировать планы выполнения запросов лучше использовать параметризованные запросы к БД.

```
string sqlExpression = "select Name, Date, Code from tRefuseTable where inn=@inn";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@inn", item.INN_Legal);
        command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name={reader[0]}, Date={reader[1]}, Code={reader[2]}");
        }
    }
}
```

По теме параметризации см. также:

- [глава из учебника на metaint](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php)
- [Медленно в приложении, быстро в SSMS](http://www.queryprocessor.ru/fast-in-ssms-slow-in-app-part3/)

Comment: @Bald Ой, точно. Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Хм, раз уж решили дать ответ - напишите как правильно формировать параметризированные запросы, а не склейкой строк

Comment: Ну и `Console.WriteLine` уже внутри имеет `string.Format`, незачем его еще раз писать: `Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Date={1}, Code={2}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);`. Не в том месте вы воспользовались преимуществом интерполяции строк